# How can I iterate over these object properties and set them accordingly in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a `User` class with subclasses like `Parent` and `Student`. In the constructor, I want to pass a `stdObject` and set each property to the same-named property in my object.

Here's what I have now:

```
     /**
     * Creates a new user from a row or blank.
     * Creates a new user from a database row if given or an empty User object if null
     * 
     * @param Object $row   A row object the users table
     */
    public function __construct(stdClass $row = null)
    {
        if ($row) {
            if (isset($row->user_id)) $this->user_id = $row->user_id;
            if (isset($row->first_name)) $this->first_name = $row->first_name;
            if (isset($row->last_name)) $this->last_name = $row->last_name;
            if (isset($row->phone)) $this->phone = $row->phone;
            if (isset($row->email)) $this->email = $row->email;
        }
    }
```

Instead of `if(isset())`'s for each property, could I use a `foreach($row as $key => $value){` and then set `$this->$key=$value`? Or does this only work for arrays?

If that does work, can I access properties using both object `->` notation and array `[]` notation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a stdClass, you could cast to array, then loop over that.

e.g.,

```
public function __construct(stdClass $row = null)
{
    if ($row) {
        $row = (array)$row;
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```